# How to set up Superset config for caching

Tags: flask, apache-superset, flask-cache

Right now, I am working on Airbnb Superset project for working purpose.

I know Superset supports cache (by Flask-Cache), but I got stuck when I set up the configuration.

My config.py file looks like this:

```
    CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60 * 24
    CACHE_CONFIG = {'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem',
                'CACHE_DIR': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/temp'),
                'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                }
```

But after I re-start the server, there is no different.

Does anyone know how to set up?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been using superset for over a year now with docker-compose, but neither the default cache nor one I set up like this works (empty thumbnails)

Answer (score 1):

I have set up the same config. It works. Although I still cannot find the cache file from `CACHE_DIR`, but from the logging, I can see the message `loaded_from_source` when I first view the dashboards/slices and will show `loaded_from_cache` within the cache timeout after first visit.

Comment: Any progress on this question? I am trying to use Redis cache in my Superset application. And it's hard to understand what the correct config should be.