# Saving Apache Superset query results to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-superset

When Apache Superset runs a query, I want to save the results to S3 so they can be further reused and not lost.

How can I configure the default output directory for Apache Superset?

Comment: Were you able to store and load query results from S3?

Answer (score 1):

Superset is a reporting tool, so the result of the queries are used for creating charts, filters, etc.
For your purpose (reusing a result), I think you should have a look to Superset Cache (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435743/how-to-set-up-superset-config-for-caching) or in the [official page](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#caching))

If you want to store the data in a CSV file in S3, I recommend that you use an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool or a custom development (with Python for instance), but that would mean defining the view in the database level (so it can be accessed from the ETL), and then reuse the view in Superset